# JAWS read extra space with span tag, or if span tag has aria tags. How to fix this extra space with JAWS

Tags: javascript, jaws-screen-reader

Using JAWS to read character by character in chrome browser, observed that JAWS read extra space when encounter span tag and also read another space if span tag contains "tabindex=0" or any aria tag like aria-pressed="false" etc e.g., `<span tabindex="0" aria-pressed="false">text</span>`

```
<!-- HTML Snippet below -->      
<div role="region" aria-label="Text">           
    text1 text2 <span aria-pressed="true" role="button" tabindex="0">text3</span></div>
```

When I use JAWS I can hear 3 space after 'text2'. How to fix this issue so that JAWS do not read these extra space when browse content through arrow key.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you’re trying to create customized checkbox or radio button switch.

Unfortunately, I’ve also faced same problem. JAWS reader behaves in unpredictable ways with up/down arrow keys.

What I would do is try to follow accessibility specs and see if it works in other screen readers. If it does, most likely it is an issue with a screen reader in question.

In above case, I am quite sure it is because I have faced the same issue under different circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

don't worry about this. JAWS has some quirks and their users are used to working with them. Even if you found a fix for your own pages, as soon as users leave your website they'll need to deal with the same issue everywhere else.
It's not a big deal and it won't fail against any accessibility guidelines, so I'd leave it alone and concentrate on issues that could cause real problems. This one shouldn't cause much of a problem for anyone.